# Modify a page request on refresh/event

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm writing a blog editor that is loaded when a POST request reaches a page, say **blog_editor.php**. The post request data looks like blog_title="This is blog title"

Now blog_editor.php reads the blog title from the post request, if it exists blog_id is read from the DB and the content is ready for editing otherwise a new DB entry is created.

Now I've given an option of inline editing of blog_title which should be saved using ajax.

`My problem here is, the page is looking for a unique blog_title. If user modifies the blog title inline and then does a page refresh, it creates a new blog with old blog_title as POST request still contains old title.`

Can I modify this post data someway?

Comment: Why not just send the `blog_id`? That won't change...

Comment: Is there a reason user would refresh page?  One would expect their data to be lost on a hard refresh.

Comment: I agree ... you will typically not be able to change POST data once it has reached the destination page. You are better off doing some type of check to see whether the post id is -1 (for say a new blog post) or 101 (for an existing post) and then acting based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to update blog title on ajax you should not use the same functionality that you are using for POST request.

In your ajax case you need blog_id because intention is to update blog which user modifies.

as per your current functionality whenever user edits title that should be consider as new title and you are getting blog_id based on title.

solution : 
In case you are not having blog_id at the first moment, put your original title in some hidden field or assign it to some javascript variable on page load and send both Original and user modified title in the Ajax request and get blog_id and descriptions based on original title and allow to edit with new title.

Comment: @Mayank Is this answer helped You?